# Does iOS really disable JavaScript in mail attachment?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

If an iOS device, say iPhone or iPad, receives an HTML file as an attachment by email,
does the iOS system automatically removes from the HTML attachment all the JavaScript scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting iOS 13 the JavaScript is disabled on the email client Html preview app.
We experienced the same problem with customer devices on iOS 13. On previous versions of iOS release, this was working fine.
I think the main problem with the enabled JS was a good amount of spam getting through emails that used it to force images to load automatically.